# jpeg "frames" to MP4 conversion, quick fix

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, jpeg, mp4, converters

How do I convert a series of jpeg images ("Test 03_0000.jpeg" to "Test 03_3000.jpeg") into an MP4 (30fps)?

I have tried Lightworks and Animotica. It did not work.

I have downloaded ffmpeg now, but tutorial tl/dr.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i "Test 03_%04d.jpeg" -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

See the [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) and [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more information.